# How come my php settings on CLI and Apache are different?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, command-line-interface, osx-lion

I am currently setting up a new Mac Mini Lion server. 
I am now installing mongodb and apc extension.
I want to include the ini settings for the extensions on the /etc/php.d directory (similar with my server settings on centOS)

I tried to do

```
php -i | grep php.d
```

and it gives me

```
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d/
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php.d/mongo.ini
PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR => /etc/php.d/
_SERVER["PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR"] => /etc/php.d/
```

But when I tried on phpinfo() on a php script, I got:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /private/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

The php environment on CLI and php script is the same
which php

> /usr/bin/php

and on php script page

> PATH  /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Is there anything I should set on the apache side?

I am thinking to stick with the Built-in apache and php from the mac installation because I like the Server App from Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like PHP CLI is using `/etc/php.ini` file, verify with:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

While Apache is loading the `/private/etc/php.ini` file:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /private/etc/php.ini
```

Point to the right `php.ini` file which you want by `PHPINIDir` directive.

---

**EDIT**

Don't know why `phpinfo()` ignore the additional .ini files but it can be force to scan in 2 ways:

1. insert the below line before starting Apache in init script

   ```
   export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR=/etc/php.d
   ```
2. add the following to the Apache configuration file:

   ```
   php_value include_path "/etc/php.d"
   ```

Comment: /etc/ directory is actually just a symlink of /private/etc/

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root   wheel          11  7 25 17:43 etc -> private/etc

Comment: I tried php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
and it gave me 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /private/etc/php.ini

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /etc/php.d/`? Run `strace -ofile -f -o /tmp/apache.log /script/to/start/apache`, paste the log to pastebin and insert link here.

Comment: for ls -l /etc/php.d/ 
-rw-rwxrwx  1 root  wheel  213 Aug 21 06:13 apc.ini
-rw-rwxrwx  1 root  wheel   19 Aug 21 06:11 mongo.ini

Comment: for strace, I dont have strace, what is that for?

Comment: Give me the result after testing the above suggested ways.

Comment: I think the step no 1 make sense, bcos in the PHP variables from CLI, it shows _SERVER["PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR"] => /etc/php.d/
but nothing on the Apache side. I define export PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR variable in the ~/.bash_profile is there any where else I can define it so that Apache can read it? thanks

Comment: I'm not a OSX guy, but I think you can define in `/usr/sbin/apachectl`. How about the second way?

Comment: @hachiari let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1142/discussion-between-quanta-and-hachiari)